# Uniqueness of $\rho = AA^*$.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, matrix-decomposition

If $\rho$ is self-adjoint and positive semi-definite so that $\rho =AA^*$, then is $A$ unique up to some transform? We may assume finite-dim Hilbert space if necessary.

Comment: It might be helpful: on a Hilbert-space, a positive operator A ($A=A*$ and $(Ax,x) \geqslant 0$) has an unique positive square-root B, i.e. $B^2=A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will mainly talk about the finite dimensional case.

So the question is asking when does $AA^* = BB^*$.

If $\rho$ is invertible (i.e. positive definite), then of course this is equivalent to $A^{-1}B$ being unitary, so $A$ and $B$ differ by a unitary transform.

If $\rho = 0$, then we have $A^*A = 0$ which implies $A = 0$ (because for any vector $x$, we have $\langle Ax, Ax\rangle = x^*A^*Ax = 0$, hence $Ax = 0$).

For general $\rho$, we may decompose it into the positive definite part and the zero part.  This completely describes all the answers to $AA^* = \rho$.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, $A,B$ differ by a partial isometry $U$, i.e., $A=BU$?

Comment: Yes, more precisely an isometry on the positive definite part of $\rho$. On the zero part they must all be zero.

Comment: I see. In that case, the result seems to be generalizable to the infinite-dim case by using polar decomposition.

Comment: Possibly... to be honest I lost most of my knowledge on Hilbert spaces due to aging, so I'm not that sure. I'm aware that a general operator can be non-invertible while injective, which doesn't occur in the finite dimensional case. But for self-ajoint ones maybe this doesn't matter. So perhaps you should fill in the details yourself, as you definitely can do it better than I (: